# postgres encode problem

Tags: postgresql, ascii, encode

I have a Postgres 8.2 database.
The table encode : **SQL-ASCII**. (I can't change this :( )
Xhtml charset: charset=**iso-8859-2**.
The files encode is **ANSII**. (notepad++)

When I show retrieved data with AJAX (jQuery) I must use **utf8_encode()**. When this data, insert into database, instead of accent letters (öüőűú) I see this  &# 245; &# 251; and others.

Question:  How can I solve this encode problem?

**EDIT**
This work me:

```
pg_dump -E LATIN9 alt > alt.sql
createdb -T template0 -E UTF8 new_database
psql -f alt.sql new_database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sounds like you're mixing utf8 encoding and html/xml escaping.

To reconfigure the database's encoding setting, the [relevant bits say](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/multibyte.html):

> The default character set is selected while initializing your PostgreSQL database cluster using initdb. It can be overridden when you create a database, so you can have multiple databases each with a different character set.

[As well as](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createdatabase.html):

```
CREATE DATABASE name
   [ [ WITH ] [ OWNER [=] dbowner ]
       [ TEMPLATE [=] template ]
       [ ENCODING [=] encoding ]
       [ TABLESPACE [=] tablespace ]
       [ CONNECTION LIMIT [=] connlimit ] ]
```

---

Edit: per horse's name, you cannot alter the database's encoding, so you may need to dump the schema and data, edit the dump accordingly, and re-create it accordingly.

Comment: You can only specify the encoding during creation of the database. You cannot change it once the database has been created. See the ALTER DATABASE command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't drop data(base), It's a  company's database.

Comment: Sorry, my English knowledge is not perfect, but now, I understand what you advised. :)